# Tell the iPhone this particular number is no phone number

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, phone-number

this is probably a fairly easy question and I think it's more amusing than anything else, but I have a webView displaying a local HTML in which there is a ISBN number of a book, and the iPhone links it as a phone number and asks whether I'd like to call it.
How would I tell it to not use it as a phone number?

(The number is plain text inside a p-tag, it's not linked to amazon or so..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
webview.dataDetectorTypes=0;
```

or in your html set

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Comment: webview.dataDetectorTypes=0; did the Job! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dataDetectorTypes` property of `UIWebView` and tell it to not identify phone numbers. This would only be in the case that your HTML doesn't have any actual phone numbers which you want clickable from within the web view.